# Why data binding does not remember the old values?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource

I have a classic ObjectDataSource and a ListView in my page. The List view just displays some data and when switched to edit template it allows the user to change the values. I want the user to edit just some values -- so I bind just these ones in the edit template.

The problem is that the other values suddenly turn to nulls or 0. I tried to bind all of the values at once and it works fine, but I cannot understand why the old/original values just disappear. Is there any way how to bind the old values?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that only the data that is included into a round-trip to the server will be available in the postback. That includes all that that is bound to BoundFields, TemplateFields or if the Propertyname is included in the DataKey (or DataKeyNames, don't know right now).

The best approach to fix this, and to keep the overhead to a minimum is to add your primary key to the DataKeyNames collection. This allows you to have access to your custom object that contains an unique identifier and all properties that have just changes.

In your Update Method of the ODS (in your custom class) you now need to retrieve the old object by its unique identifier, manually assign the new values and saves your object back to the database

Comment: I've set the DataKeyNames to my primary key and it works fine... Thanks for help.

Comment: Took me hours the first time I encountered this. I'm glad that I could help your. I hope it saved you some trouble ;)